# Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null in jest react-native

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm having a problem when testing react native using jest

```
● Test suite failed to run

Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.

  at invariant (node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:20:15)
  at new NativeEventEmitter (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js:41:7)
  at RNFBNativeEventEmitter.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/RNFBNativeEventEmitter.js:22:232)
  at new RNFBNativeEventEmitter (node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/RNFBNativeEventEmitter.js:37:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/RNFBNativeEventEmitter.js:69:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/registry/nativeModule.js:19:54)
```